# Execute nginx exe in folder with -s reload args Consul template Windows

Tags: nginx, consul, consul-template

I am using Consul Template V0.19.0 ***for windows***, for rendering nginx loadbalancing config.It is working as expected.

Now I want the consul template, to execute the nginx exe in a folder with args (-s reload) as below:-

**Case 1:**

```
template {
source = "Template/template.ctmpl"
destination = "F:\\IDE\\Visual Studio Collection\\Web Servers\\nginx-
1.12.0\\nginx-1.12.0\\conf\\nginx.conf"
command = "F:\\IDE\\Visual Studio Collection\\Web Servers\\nginx-
1.12.0\\nginx-1.12.0\\nginx -s reload"
command_timeout = "60s"
}
```

But it throws error like, "failed to execute command "F:\IDE\Visual Studio Collection\Web Servers\nginx-1.12.0\nginx-1.12.0\nginx.exe" from "Template/template.ctmpl" => "F:\IDE\Visual Studio Collection\Web Servers\nginx-1.12.0\nginx-1.12.0\conf\nginx.conf": child: exec: "F:IDEVisual": file does not exist".

**Case 2:-**
Currently I have achieved this by making the nginx as service (using nssm) and gave the command like,

```
command = "powershell restart-service nginx"
```

instead of giving the full path followed by "-s reload".

But for this, have to make the nginx as a service using apps like nssm.

May I know, is there any way to tell the command attribute in the consul template config to, "execute the nginx exe in folder like in the **Case 1**" ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
template {
source = "Template/template.ctmpl"
destination = "F:\\IDE\\Visual Studio Collection\\Web Servers\\nginx-
1.12.0\\nginx-1.12.0\\conf\\nginx.conf"
command = "\"F:\\IDE\\Visual Studio Collection\\Web Servers\\nginx-
1.12.0\\nginx-1.12.0\\nginx\" -s reload"
command_timeout = "60s"
}
```

If that doesn't work try below options also for command

```
command = "\"F:/IDE/Visual Studio Collection/Web Servers/nginx-
1.12.0/nginx-1.12.0/nginx\" -s reload"
```

or

```
command = "\"F:\\\\IDE\\\\Visual Studio Collection\\\\Web Servers\\\\nginx-
1.12.0\\\\nginx-1.12.0\\\\nginx\" -s reload"
```

**Edit-1**

So based on the discussion, it seems that your nginx config has a relative folder based config. When nginx is started from a folder, then it also needs to be reloaded from the same folder. So you need to changed to the folder and then execute the reload command. Two formats that you should try are

```
command="cd '<NGINX FOLDER PATH>' && nginx -s reload"
```

or

```
command="cmd /k 'cd \'<NGINX FOLDER PATH>\' && nginx -s reload'"
```

Comment: Hi @tarun: The 2nd and 3rd command produces the following error.  "* failed to execute command "\"F:\\\\IDE\\\\Visual Studio Collection\\\\Web Servers\\\\nginx-1.12.0\\\\nginx-1.12.0\\\\nginx.exe\" -s reload" from "Template/template.ctmpl" => "F:\\IDE\\Visual Studio Collection\\Web Servers\\nginx-1.12.0\\nginx-1.12.0\\conf\\nginx.conf": child: command exited with a non-zero exit status:
    F:\IDE\Visual Studio Collection\Web Servers\nginx-1.12.0\nginx-1.12.0\nginx.exe -s reload  This is assumed to be a failure. Please ensure the command exits with a zero exit status."Any idea on this one.Thx

Comment: Can you run the command manually in Command line and see what exit code it exits with ?

Comment: Hi @Tarun. 
>>>Tried by "Exe Path" -s reload. But it says like "nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: CreateFile() "logs/error.log" fail
ed (3: The system cannot find the path specified)". 
>>> Tried all the command value which u suggested gives "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." 
Am i missing something here? Could u help me out. Thx.

Comment: This means nginx is not running in the first place. You need to create the logs directory and then only it will be able to start

Comment: Hi @Tarun. Ah no. Nginx is running in task manager. And the log folder also exists. Any other thing I am missing out.. Could u point out. Thx.

Comment: Run a command line with admin rights and then try your debugging

Comment: Ah, already running the cmd in admin mode. Tried again. But no luck. Same error it is producing. Any other clue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151950/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-nandakumar).

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue child: exec: "C:nginx": file does not exist".

No solution above neither others on web didnt work.

But i have finaly found solution.

Using `choco install nginx-service 1.24.0` (which install nginx and nssm, manual installation can works to i think but this is more simply way)

Template with command which start bat in which is a nginx service

```
template {
  source = "c:\\consul\\template.ctmpl"
  destination = "C:\\tools\\nginx\\conf.d\\nginx-location.conf"
  wait {
    min = "2s"
    max = "13s"
  }
 command = "C:\\consul\\test.bat"
 command_timeout = "60s"
}
```

test.bat

```
powershell restart-service nginx-service
```

ps. my whole solution is for adressing (reverse proxy) for invidual containers of same task which are in nomad cluster connected to consul. And now finally works.